# Adding multiple strings as numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have the following piece of code that converts multiple strings into number, which works fine, but I don't like the way it looks and want to know if I could write it in a better way.

```
  Number(result.channels.electricity.chan[0].day[0]._)
+ Number(result.channels.electricity.chan[1].day[0]._)
+ Number(result.channels.electricity.chan[2].day[0]._)
+ Number(result.channels.electricity.chan[3].day[0]._)
+ Number(result.channels.electricity.chan[4].day[0]._)
+ Number(result.channels.electricity.chan[5].day[0]._)
```

Is there a cleaner way of writing this?

Comment: numerous ways to wrap a loop around this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reduce is pretty simple:

```
var sum = results.channels.electricity.chan.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a + Number(b.day[0]._);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `while` loop

```js
var channels = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], i = -1, res = 0;
while (++i < channels.length ) res += Number(channels[i]);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my data structure doesn't allow me to use this.

Comment: @Bazinga777 _"my data structure doesn't allow me to use this"_ Can describe why data structure does not allow approach ? Is data structure an array ?

Comment: I am parsing an xml file parsed to json which looks pretty bad, so this would create a bit of a mess

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. With some ES6-7 features:

```
let chans = results.channels.electricity.chan;
let total = chans.reduce((sum, { day: [ { _ } ] }) => (sum + Number(_)), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can do.

1. Small fix to improve readability would be to assign the chan property to a variable so you don't have to repeat the whole path.  E.g. `var chan = result.channels.electricity.chan`
2. Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the array elements and increment a variable inside the loop.